# Can a US firm legally hire someone as intern after they have graduated from school/university and aren't enrolled in any school/university?

Tags: united-states, california, workplace

Can a firm US based in the United States legally hire someone as intern after they have graduated from school/university and aren't enrolled in any school/university anymore?

If state-dependent, I am interested in California.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can call any position an internship without a school being involved. However you need to pay them. An unpaid internship at a for profit organization is only possible if it earns some kind of school credit for the intern.